# Retrieving data from social media

Tags: php, twitter

I would like to retrieve tweets from twitter for a particular user and store it in my local database. Is it possible to do so? If it yes how can we do?

Comment: Twitter have their own API, and there will be plenty of examples on this site on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Twitter REST API functions.
You will find the doc [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public)

To get the timeline for an user you can check the GET statuses/user_timeline function [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline), decode the json response and store it in your database.